# How to show dock using keyboard in Full screen mode?

Tags: macos, mac

I know the normal way is to move mouse to the bottom of screen. But this method is slow, sometimes not responsive (have to drag a few times before the dock shows up).

Question:

**Is there a keyboard shortcut to show dock in fullscreen mode?**

Comment: Just to clarify something which might improve your experience: the normal way is not to move the mouse to the bottom of the screen, but to move it ‘beyond’ the bottom of the screen. That is, when you want the Dock to show, keep moving your mouse down even once it's at the bottom of the screen and the Dock will show instantly. This is a feature to prevent the Dock showing inadvertently and is quite natural once the premise is understood.